# Getting time on button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, timedelta

I just want to know how to set some variable to have value of exact time when button was clicked. For example on button click I want variable a to have time a = 19:10:23. Is that possible?

Comment: I think what you need is System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do System.currentTimeMillis() or you could create a calendar instance.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Or

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

If you use System.currentTimeMillis() you can use that to create a Date object or Calendar Object.

```
Date date = new Date(currentTime);
```